# How to solve 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure' error when subplotting?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, subplot

I want to plot my all dataframess 'oran' column with using subplot.

data contains 'oran' column.

Here is my code;

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(6,2, figsize=(20,20))
for ax in axes:
    for month in dftm.month_base_valor.unique():
        temp = dftm[dftm.month_base_valor.eq(month)]
        #display(temp)
        temp.oran.plot(ax=ax)
fig.tight_layout()
```

But this code gives me the error
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure'

I couldn't find the way to solve this problem.
How can i avoid this error?

The first 5 row of the dataset

```
month_base_valor    aylık_total valor_tarihi    gunluk_total    oran    year
0   2017-01 11111.50    20170102    11111.37    0.00    2017
1   2017-01 11111.50    20170103    11111.66    0.00    2017
2   2017-01 11111.50    20170104    11111.97    0.00    2017
3   2017-01 11111.50    20170105    11111.09    0.01    2017
4   2017-01 11111.50    20170106    11111.74    0.01    2017
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is from somewhere in the mentioned code? Didn't you call `get_figure` function somewhere else?

Comment: No i didnt call the get_figure, its in ---->  temp.oran.plot(ax=ax)

Comment: Please provide us with your dataframe or at least a part of it in order for us to find out what's going on.

Comment: I added first rows @AmirhosseinKiani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `axes` is a 2-dimensional array (shape `(6,2)`).

The loop `for ax in axes: ...` selects 1d arrays (shape `(2,)`) out of it. Passing this array as `ax`-kwarg  to `temp.oran.plot(ax=ax)` results in the respective error.

Using `for ax in axes.flat:  ...` should work.